# Android android:keepScreenOn

Tags: android

i am creating a custom ui component for android ,its working fine, but how to add android:keepScreenOn to this custom UI component ,so that i could set android:keepScreenOn="true" for the custom component

Comment: Look into `AttributeSet`. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+attributeset

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setKeepScreenOn(boolean screenOn)` will solve